# Calculate after X days from today

Tags: php

i am develop a webpage in that i need to calculate x days from a specified date , The problem is we exclude the saturday and sunday . For example $Shipdate = '06/30/2009' and the x is 5 means , i want the answer '7' [ie 30 is tuesday so after 5 days it will be sunday , so there is two holiday(saturday and sunday) so we add 5+2(for saturday and sunday)]=7. Please help me to find out , Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really accept an answer if you find one that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will need to be able to specify a calendar with significant days excluded. Consider Christmas Day or public holidays. [This](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/807) appears to be code that will consider public holidays, you need to modify it or parameterise it with your set of holidays.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// ** Set Beginning and Ending Dates, in YYYY-mm-dd format **
 $begin = '2008-01-01';
 $end = '2008-03-31';
 $begin_mk = strtotime("$begin"); 
 $end_mk = strtotime("$end");

// ** Calculate number of Calendar Days between the two dates
 $datediff = ( $end_mk > $begin_mk ? ( $end_mk - $begin_mk ) : ( $begin_mk - $end_mk ) );
 $days = ( ( $datediff / 3600 ) / 24 );
  $days = $days + 1; // to be inclusive of last date;

// ** Count days excluding Sundays **
  $iteration = 0; 
  $numDaysExSunday = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=$days; $i++) {
  $weekday = date("w", strtotime("$begin + $iteration day"));
       echo "$weekday<br>";
     **// i change only this line to add saturday**
     if ($weekday !== '0' && $weekday !== '6') {
        $numDaysExSunday++;
     }
  $iteration++; 
}

// ** Output number of days excluding Sundays **
echo $numDaysExSunday;
?>
```

i take it from

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/Q_23499410.html

the solution Excluding Sundays but need to change only one line to exclude saturday i write it in the code

Comment: You should rename the variable as well, and also include holidays.  I would replace the weekday comparison with a function that returns whether it's a business day.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Weekdays($start,$end){
    $days=0;
    if ( $end <= $start ) {
        // This is invalid data.
        // You may consider zero to be valid, up to you.
        return; // Or throw an error, whatever.
    }
    while($start<$end){
        $dayofweek = date('w',$start);
        if( 6!= $dayofweek && 0 != $dayofweek){
            $days++;
        }
        $start = strtotime('+1 day',$start);
    }
    return $days;
}
```

You may want to tweak it a bit depending on whether you want to count it as one day or zero if the start is the same day as the end.